# What does preliminary degree overview mean?

Tags: graduate-admissions

I am reviewing the documents needed for a graduate program application. One of the documents is degree certificate. But for those who have not yet received it, it is stated that they can upload preliminary degree overview instead. What exactly is preliminary degree overview?

Answer (score 2):

When applications for graduate programs are due, often the applicant does not have the degree qualifying for the graduate degree already in their pocket.

However, there is often the possibility to get an official document that shows the achievements of the student until the issuing date of the document. The "preliminary degree overview" is one name for this, while "transcript" is another (probably more common) one.

For applications, this document needs to show grades and courses that you took. An official letter stating for how long you have been studying will almost surely *not* do.